# Store indices of neighbouring cells which fall within a certain radius

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a very large numpy array of 1s and 0s. I want to go row by row and look for all the 1s. Once I encounter a 1, I want to store the indices of entries which fall inside a radius of five rows. This is better illustrated in the picture:

[image]

(in the picture I only show half a circle, in the real case I need the indices of the values that fall inside the entire circle) 
Once I collect the indices, I go to the next 1 in the array and do the same. Once I finish looping through the array I want to set all the values of the collected indices which are not 1 to 1. In a sense, I am creating a buffer around all 1s with a radius of 5 columns.

```
for row in myarray: 
    for column in myarray:
        dist = math.sqrt(row**2+column**2) 
        if dist <= 5  
        .........store the indices of the neighbouring cells
```

Can you please give me a suggestion how to accomplish this?
[image]

Comment: Do you really want to store the indices or is that just an intermediate step that could be neglected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation you are describing is called [dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_%28morphology%29). I you have scipy, you could use [ndimage.binary_dilation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html) to obtain the result:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.zeros((21, 21))
arr[5, 5] = arr[15, 15] = 1

i, j = np.ogrid[:11, :11]
# struct = ((i-5)**2 + (j-5)**2 <= 40)
struct = np.abs(i-5)+ np.abs(j-5) <= 8

result = ndimage.binary_dilation(arr, structure=struct)
plt.imshow(result, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a small question. When I draw the buffer circles with radius 5 on a piece of paper for the situation given above, I cover partially some more cells. When I change the function to (i-5)**2 + (j-5)**2 <= 26, I manage to capture some more cells. My problem is at the edges of the circle. In reality, I should capture 7 cells at each of the four edges as shown in the added picture. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You could use `((i-5)**2 + (j-5)**2 <= 40)` or `np.abs(i-5)+ np.abs(j-5) <= 8`. The first condition I found by mindless trial-and-error, the second works because the line defined by `x+y = constant` is a diagonal in the positive quadrant -- just what you need. Note also that you don't *need* to define `struct` using an equation -- you can use an arbitrary list of lists of boolean values if you wish. (Try `struct = [[False, True, False], [True, True, True], [False, True, False]]` to see what I mean.)